# Could the compiler vectorize the looping with an array which consists of an array inside?

Tags: fortran, vectorization, gfortran

I would like to vectorize this code below (just for an example), just assume somehow I should write an array inside an array.

```
PROGRAM TEST

  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL, DIMENSION(2000):: A,B,C  !100000
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(2000):: E
  REAL(KIND=8):: TIME1,TIME2
  INTEGER::I

  DO I=1, 2000       !Actually only this loop could be vectorized
     B(I)=100.00     !by the compiler 
     C(I)=200.00
     E(I)=I  
  END DO

  !Computing computer's running time (start)
  CALL CPU_TIME (TIME1)

  DO I=1, 2000               !This is the problem, somehow I should put
     A(E(I))=B(E(I))*C(E(I)) !an integer array E(I) inside an array 
  END DO                     !I would like to vectorize this loop also, but it didn't work

  PRINT *, 'Results  =', A(2000)
  PRINT *, '   '

  !Computing computer's running time (finish)
  CALL CPU_TIME (TIME2)

  PRINT *, 'Elapsed real time = ', TIME2-TIME1, 'second(s)'

END PROGRAM TEST
```

I thought at first time, that compiler could understand what I want which somehow be vectorized like this:

```
DO I=1, 2000, 4   !Unrolled 4 times
   A(E(I))=B(E(I))*C(E(I))
   A(E(I+1))=B(E(I+1))*C(E(I+1))
   A(E(I+2))=B(E(I+2))*C(E(I+2))
   A(E(I+3))=B(E(I+3))*C(E(I+3))
END DO
```

but I was wrong. I used: `gfortran -Ofast -o -fopt-info-optimized Tes.F95` and I got the information that only the first looping was successfully to be vectorized.

Do you have any idea how I could vectorize it? Or can't it be vectorized at all?

Comment: When you use indirect indexing (i.e. as in your expressions such as `A(E(I))`) you have no reasonable right to expect elements such as `A(E(I-1))` and `A(E(I+1))` to be anywhere near it in memory. Vectorisation depends on the processor being able to stream a number of adjacent array elements onto its f-p units in a chunk.  I haven't given it a lot of thought but it strikes me that indirect addressing is probably incompatible with vectorisation.  In HPC it's not unknown to re-order array elements precisely to get the benefits of spatial locality of data.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: So in other words, the vectorization by the compiler is only possible with DIRECT INDEXING as written on the DO statements?

Comment: That's my thinking, but I'm willing to be told otherwise.  Why not spend some time with pencil and paper and figure some of it out for yourself.

Comment: To have any chance of effective vectorization with indirect indexing, you require a recent instruction set target. Avx512 adds support for this, but such cpu isn't widely available. If you do compile for such a target, an up to date compiler is important.  Openmp-simd may persuade gfortran to vectorize for axv256 even though it appears inefficient.

Comment: @tim18: Thanks. Do you mean ''Openmp-simd may persuade gfortran to vectorize for axv256'' that the syntax is same with the Intel Fortran's one?

Comment: OpenMP simd is a standard thing, not Intel's. Intel has its own DIR directives, but that is different.

Answer (score 1):

If E hase equal values for different I, then you would be manipulating the same elements of A multiple times, in which case the order could matter. (Though not in your case.) Also, if you have multiple index arrays, like E1, E2 and E3, and

```
DO I=1, 2000              
   A(E3(I))=B(E1(I))*C(E2(I)) 
END DO
```

the order could matter too. So I think this kind of indexing is not in general allowed in parallel loops.

Comment: Hen hej, I see we think alike Herr Ostrom!

Comment: Compilers which auto-vectorize this will preserve the order of storage in case of duplicates (unless you specifically direct that you don't care).  In case it's not obvious, the arrays cannot overlap in the posted example (which is trivial enough to possibly be optimized down to nothing).

Comment: @tim18 ok, but it seems he does indeed get an error (or 'information') when trying to compile, but you mean this is because his hardware doesn't support this? I do not think openMP would allow it, but I haven't tried this particular arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

With ifort one can use !DIR$ IVDEP which is "ignore Vector dependence". It only works when E(I) is linear as in the example...

Assuming that one wants to do all the indexes then just replace (E(i)) with (I) and work out the obvious E(I) order later...